# What's the name of this Powerful lemma?

Tags: number-theory

I have read a book,post this

**Lemma**:  Let $p$ be a prime then if $p-1 | k $ one has
$$\sum_{i=1}^{p} i^k \equiv -1 \pmod p$$
and if $p-1 \not | k$ then one has
$$\sum_{i=1}^{p} i^k \equiv 0 \pmod p$$

I can understand this lemma proof:

**proof :**
The first assertion is obvious as each term will contribute $1$ except for $p^k$ which is $0$ and for the second, let the sum be $S$ and note that $g^kS \equiv S \pmod p$ where $g$ is a primitive root $\pmod p$. Since $g^k \not \equiv 1 \pmod p$ then one must have $S \equiv 0 \pmod p$.By done!

**Question:I fell this lemma is very powefull,and  have other methods to prove this lemma?and what's the name of the lemma?or have some Application to paper?**

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/707013/11619) or [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1783529/11619) or [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/114903/11619) for earlier incarnations involving my posts alone. Undoubtedly there are even older occurrences. The theme is a sum over a finite subgroup of the multiplicative group of a field. Either the sum vanishes or consists of several $1$s. Occurs very often in character sums and exponential- sums. I certainly didn't invent the trick :-) Other proofs come from the formula for a geometric sum.

Comment: Should follow easily from Faulhaber's formula https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula

Answer (score 4):

With high probability, this lemma doesn't have a **name** attributed to some author. One  may simply call it a *"congruence for integer power sums"*.

See the 2010 article by Kieren MacMillan and Jonathan Sondow,   [Proofs of Power Sum and Binomial Coefficient Congruences Via Pascal’s Identity](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1011.0076.pdf) , which is exclusively devoted to this lemma and still doesn't name if after somebody.

In this article, there are references to many alternative **methods of proof**, e.g.   relying  on the theory of primitive roots, or invoking Lagrange’s theorem, or employing Bernoulli numbers and finite differences.

Even more interestingly, this article presents a new elementary proof, using an identity for power sums proven by **Pascal in 1654**. This shows that technically it was possible that the lemma was known to Pascal or other people 350 years ago.

Further, the article also gives numerous references to **applications**, e.g. to prove theorems on Bernoulli numbers (Staudt-Clausen, Carlitz-von Staudt, Almkvist-Meurman) and to study the Erdös-Moser Diophantine equation as well as other exponential Diophantine equations and Stirling numbers of the second kind.

Also other standard volumes do not give the lemma a **name**, e.g. the classic textbook by G. H. Hardy and E. M. Wright,
[An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers](http://matematica.cubaeduca.cu/medias/pdf/842.pdf)
, where it appears as theorem 119. This again supports that the lemma most likely does not have a name.
Also in here, the **application** is given to prove von Staudt's theorem.

Comment: Nice reference! (+1)

Comment: We were just 350-ish years too late to call it the “MacMillan-Sondow Lemma”… ;)